# Ordering with "inversed" indexes

Tags: javascript

im trying to achieve an "array-sorting". But I need to do this in this way:

```
array["element0"] = 5
array["element1"] = 3
array["element2"] = 4
```

Each index is the element id and the value of that index is the order. In the most cases is done with order as indexes and the expression:

```
arr.splice(to, 0, array.splice(from,1)[0]);
```

But I need to reorder the values of the array and not the indexes.

Any kind of idea?

Comment: This doesn't look like `array`, it is `object`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an array then you can directly use `reverse()` of javascript on array if you wish to reverse an array.

For example:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.reverse();
```

Result will be : `Mango,Apple,Orange,Banana`

Note: This won't work if your variable is an object.